# Why doesn't list insert with negative index insert the item at the end?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list `x`, if I `insert` at -1, it is not inserting the "hello" at the last index of the list:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3] then
>>> x.insert(-1, "hello")
>>> print(x)
[1, 2, 'hello', 3]
```

Why doesn't -1 not insert the "hello" at the last index of the list?

Since -1 index refers to the last item of the list, I was expecting:

```
[1, 2, 3, "hello"]
```

Comment: @glibdud: I was not asking "how to insert at the last?" My question was why index with -1 didn't insert the item at the last?(as -1 always refers to the last index of the list)

Comment: `x.insert(-1, "hello")` this won't work because **-1** is not an index of an array. If you want to access the last index of the array then you have to specify the array inside the `insert()` like this... `a.insert(a[-1], 'hello')`

Comment: @Farhan -1 is a valid index, just python will insert before it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.append(item)` is to append to the end.

`.insert(index, item)` inserts to the place *before* another item. To "insert" to end, use `.insert(len(x), item)`.

Read more at [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 6):

Running `help` on method will usually give you the answer for these kind of questions:

```
help(list.insert)
#Help on method_descriptor:
#
#insert(self, index, object, /)
#    Insert object before index.
```

Answer (score 4):

From Google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists

> list.insert(index, elem) -- inserts the element at the given index, shifting elements to the right.

Insert should be read as: "insert *elem* **before** the **index**", which in your case means "insert 'hello' before the -1'th element (last element of the list) which is 3".

To insert to the end of the lists you should use `list.append(elem)` instead.

> list.append(elem) -- adds a single element to the end of the list.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add an element in the last using `insert()` function, then you have to specify the total length as index. You cannot use negative indexes. Negative indexes will start inserting from second last position and before.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.insert(len(x),'hello')
x
   [1, 2, 3, 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add value at the end of the list. There is two way to add.

**- Append:**  As the name says it will append (add) value to the last of the list

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> x.append('hello')
>>> x 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'hello']
```

**- Insert:** Now in Insert you have to give the position where you want to add the value.
so when you write

```
>>> x.insert(len(x),5)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'hello', 5]
```

You are defining as to put value 5 at position *len(x) ie 5*