# Insert element into a List with Negative index

Tags: python

When using positive index for insert it exactly inserts at the location but when using negative index for example -1 it actually inserts at -2.

```
>>> list3
[1, 9, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 19, 7]
>>> list3.insert(-1, 99)
>>> list3
[1, 9, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 19, 99, 7]
```

The documentation says at the position:

> Insert an item at a given position.

What would be the reason of this?

Comment: The proper answer to the "why" is probably given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932751/9769953): the element is inserted *before* the given current index (i.e., the documentation seems somewhat misleading and could be rephrased).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "append" method

```
list3.append(99)
```